# kubernetes ingress not updating

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I updated my ingress.yaml by adding a new path e.g. instead of example.com/ i added example.com/dev/. i deleted the old ingress and deployed the new ingress but still my app gets redirected to old example.com and on accessing example.com/dev/ i get "The requested resource was not found on this server."  I am using the same old tls certificate since the hostname is still example.com. When i describe my ingress i get :

```
Name:             example-ingress
Namespace:        dev-env
Address:          
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
TLS:
  selfsigned-cert terminates example.com
Rules:
  Host                   Path  Backends
  ----                   ----  --------
  example.com  
                         /dev/static   app-svc:80 (172.16.0.29:80)
                         /dev/(.*)     app-svc:8000 (172.16.0.29:8000)
Annotations:             
                         kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
                         nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 20m
                         nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
Events:                  <none>
```

my ingress file is :

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  namespace: prod-env
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
      secretName: selfsigned-cert
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /dev/static
            backend:
              serviceName: app-svc
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /dev/(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: app-svc
              servicePort: 8000
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: 192.168.0.19
        hostname: example.com
```

Comment: Have you checked in browser  incognito  mode. TRY private  windows  in your browser  as rewrite might be in cache

Comment: @TayburRahaman HiI just tried that but still the same results.

Comment: Can you check the the ingress controller  pod log and update the question  with log

Answer (score 0):

Please apply the same port as 8000 or 80 for both services:

```
- host: example.com
  http:
    paths:
      - path: /dev/static
        backend:
          serviceName: app-svc
          servicePort: 8000
      - path: /dev/(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: app-svc
          servicePort: 8000
```

or

```
- host: example.com
  http:
    paths:
      - path: /dev/static
        backend:
          serviceName: app-svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /dev/(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: app-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

Also try to change annotation to: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: $2`

Take look: [ingress-path](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1120), [ingress-rewrite-target](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target).

Comment: but both ports are for different purposes. One for the app and the other for /static files ?

Comment: i tried doing that but it didn't help. Also i noticed that nginx.conf for my nginx controller doesn't have updated paths. it still has old locations '/' and '/static' for the hostname example.com

Comment: Speaking about ports : your example with two different  will not work.  The ingress spec do not allows multiple backends for the same path. As a workaround I think it would be good  to use different host per service. If your new configuration fails, it will use the old configuration. Can you check your error logs to see if the new configuration is successful? Please check if the image quay.io/aledbf/nginx-ingress-controller:0.130 solves the issue.